# Android custom Listview containing different sub lists with header images

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display a custom listview containing different lists with header images(like for Contacts grouped alphabetically). Similar to the list shown in this link: https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/
And, I want to add the items to the listview at the runtime. Also, want to filter the listview accordingly. Any suggestions...

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the source in the link you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the same link I mentioned in the question :)
https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/